# Swift Apple Sign In does't Appearing app logo on sign in with apple screen?

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

I am trying to implement apple sign in on my app when i am cliking on apple sign in button can't appearing apple logo on sign in screen.can any one please help me why my app logo was not comming [image]

Answer (score 0):

How to show logo:

1. Create App id with bundle id which corresponds to your project's App bundle id in xcode (With apple sign-capability):

[image]

[image]

2. Add logos to your app in xcode

[image]

3. Publish your app to appstore;

Logo will appear.